# Core Data: Fetching Relationship Attributes

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

Can't seem to figure out the trick to fetch an attribute from a relationship when limiting the fetch to a number of properties. In the code below "thumbnail" is a transformable UIImage attribute of the entity "Photo". That always comes back fine in the array of dictionaries with the key "thumbnail". What I cannot figure out is the second property/attribute where "previewImage" is a relationship in Photo to another entity named "Image" that has a transformable attribute "uiImage" (which is a UIImage).

I've tried this:

```
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"thumbnail", @"previewImage.uiImage"]];
```

but I got this error:

```
-[NSExpressionDescription valueTransformerName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13078920
```

and I've tried this:

```
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"thumbnail", @"previewImage"]];
```

where I do get two items in each dictionary

```
{
   previewImage = "0xbabba90 <x-coredata://03FF7129-1345-4BAE-A74E-2FF5A2B38CDC/Image/p5>";
   thumbnail = "<UIImage: 0xbabbc60>";
}
```

but when I try to use that "Image" object as below

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.photos objectAtIndex:0];
Image *theImage = (Image *)[dict objectForKey:@"previewImage"];
[self.delegate photoCollectionViewController:self didSelectPreviewImage:theImage.uiImage];
```

I get this error

```
"[_NSObjectID_48_0 uiImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbabba90"
```

And I've even thrown this in the request

```
[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[@"previewImage.uiImage"]];
```

So, I guess I'm flailing and not getting this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Photo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
```

Comment: The reference to `_NSObjectID_48_0` suggests that you used `NSManagedObjectIDResultType` somewhere, though your code says `NSDictionaryResultType`. Did you ask for object IDs somewhere?

Comment: No. I searched my entire project for "NSManagedObjectIDResultType" and  nothing there. I didn't even know you could change the result type until I tried to limit fetched properties :) BTW, I have your book ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `NSDictionaryResultType` you can conveniently fetch the properties of an entity. It is not meant for traversing relationships. That is why you get an error when you do what would be logical: to fetch `previewImage.uiImage`.

From the docs:

> The property descriptions may represent attributes, to-one relationships, or expressions.

Maybe you are still thinking in terms of a database query, where you selectively choose the "fields" to fetch. This is not necessary in Core Data, which is an **object graph, not a database**.

Instead, just fetch your `NSManagedObject`s. If you are worried about memory, you shouldn't be. Core data uses a mechanism called *faulting* to fetch only what it needs. Indeed the above cryptic `"<x-coredata://03FF7129-1345-4BAE-A74E-2FF5A2B38CDC/Image/p5>"` is pretty similar to how a fault wold be displayed in the console.

Try to do your fetch with normal entities. You can expect it to "just work".

Comment: Yeah, I went back to the "old" way. I was trying to be too "smart" because I had some attributes on Photo like NSData for an image that I did not want fetched or faulted (and that's actually the reason I have the uiImage in another entity now). So, the rest of the attributes for Photo are all lightweight now. BUT, I'd still like to know how to do it :)

Comment: You can do it, but you have to use **2** fetches. I think it should be obvious how to do that. See my edit to the answer to explain why you cannot do it in one.

Comment: It's just that I've seen code (maybe not ever tested) in SO, that show things like previewImage.uiImage. Maybe they thought that should work too and never tried to actually do it???